# Why does my app have so many page faults?

Tags: macos, cocoa, unix, memory-management

I've got a mac/cocoa app that runs permanently in the background (it puts a non-interactive widget on the desktop).

After running for a long time (days), the `top` command says it has made over 600 million faults (and the number is growing slowly but constantly). Compare this to the dock which only has 7 million faults and has been running for about twice as long.

It's only using about 10MB of RAM and doesn't have any memory leaks (I'm using ARC btw). There is a simple animation that runs constantly.

Is this indicative of a problem in my code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried running under the allocations instrument? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Maybe your application just doesn't run as often as the dock (it blocks for longer periods of time) and so parts of it get paged out more often. Then those parts have to be paged back in when it *does* run. It doesn't sound like a problem at all!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run as often as the dock"? My app is running constantly. Approximately once per second a timer triggers, which does some basic math (against the current timestamp) then triggers a few core animation opacity changes which will finish animating at the moment when the timer fires again. That's pretty much all the app does.

Comment: @ChrisDevereux what should I look for in Instruments? Nothing really stands out to me when I run it, I just see a lot of allocations (mostly by CoreGraphics, if I'm reading it correctly).

Comment: If you are making a lot of avoidable allocations then that might indicate a problem with your code that is causing an increase in paging. Otherwise, the difference between your app and the dock is likely just down to them doing different things.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `fs_usage` tool which would show you system calls and page faults related to filesystem activity in real-time. For example:

```
sudo fs_usage cmd_or_PID
```

Alternatively use `dtruss` (as root with `-fp PID` or `-fn cmd`) to examine your process.